# CameraRoll react-native smartAlbum

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera-roll

It's possible to fetch photos with camera roll but filtred by smart albums like: Selfies, Screeenshots etc..? I try with this:

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos({ groupName: 'Favorites', groupTypes: 'Library', first: 36 })
.then((data) => {
  const assets = data.edges;
  const images = assets.map((asset) => {
    console.log('Imagen', asset);
    return asset.node.group_name;
  });
  console.log('CameraRoll images', data, images);
})
.catch(err => console.log('CameraRoll error', err));
```

But always return a empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because react-native use ALAssetsLibrary, and I need to use use the Photos framework, so a solution it's integrate react-native-photos-framework

https://github.com/olofd/react-native-photos-framework